# How to show the google map in full container without gray color

Tags: html, css, angularjs, google-maps

I am showing google map to show some markers anywhere in the world, to show that i am using the following code:

```
 var locationMap;
        $scope.initializeLocationMap = function() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 1,
                center: latlng

            };
            locationMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("locationMap"),
                myOptions);
        };
```

Displaying correctly in normal resolution screens. But in a bigger resolution, the container which is having 814px width and 823px height is displaying map in the middle, the top and bottom gap is filled with grey color, How to show the whole container with map, not with grey color.
 
 I am getting the map like below
[image]

Comment: Don't let the user zoom out to the point where the grey is showing. Set a minZoom on the map of 2, or 3, for instance.

Comment: try setting container width: 100% or as required and height:auto

Comment: @Adam what if the minZoom is set to 2 and let the user to zoom out to the point, and also minZoom  2 is not showing the world map correctly in normal screens. it is showing correctly in bigger resolution

Comment: @ThilakRaj - if you don't want the grey to show, you can't let the user zoom to a point where it will show (e.g. where the world starts to wrap). There's no CSS you can put on it to prevent the user zooming out to where the world starts to wrap (and you get grey), all you can do is set a minZoom.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your response, minZoom 2 is not showing the world map correctly in normal screens. it is showing correctly in bigger resolution

Comment: Ok, then you if you aren't willing to prevent the user from zooming out all the way, then you have to set your container, not to a fixed height, but to an aspect ratio (48.5% looks about good to for google maps to prevent any grey from showing up): https://jsfiddle.net/5n27wkvp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
            <body id="googleMap"  style="width:100%;height:400px;">

            <script>
            function myMap() {
            var mapProp= {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),zoom:5,
            };
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
            }
            </script>
            </body>
```